# iOS Core Data encryption

Tags: ios, core-data, encryption

I have been encrypting core-data fields using 'SecKeyWrapper' class provided in one of Apple's document. The SecKeyWrapper class is non-ARC. I'm wondering if this is still the best way to encrypt core-data fields or is there newer/better solution available ?

Thank you

Comment: would be great to know why this question is being down-voted so that I can improve my question in a better way, otherwise there is no meaning to the down-votes :)

Comment: FYI: if you hover over the down-vote arrow, it says "**This question does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or not useful". That is my guess as to the reason for down-votes.

Answer (score 30):

In [iOS 5 and later](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW1) Core Data by default uses NSFileProtection to protect persisted data.

> For apps built for iOS 5.0 or later, persistent stores now store data by default in an encrypted format on disk. The default protection level prevents access to the data until after the user unlocks the device for the first time. You can change the protection level by assigning a custom value to the NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey key when configuring your persistent stores. For additional information about the data protection that are new in iOS 5.0, see “Data Protection Improvements.”

If you want to modify the default file protection behavior for your Core Data store, change the value for the key [NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001180-SW3) to a different [NSFileProtectionKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW109) value in your store options dictionary.

Example:

```
NSDictionary *storeOptions = @{NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey  : NSFileProtectionComplete};

if (![coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:[self storeURL] options:storeOptions error:&error]){
     [self presentError:error];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @quellish. I'll try this approach. Will comeback if I have any questions.

Comment: Be careful.  "The default protection level prevents access to the data until after the user unlocks the device for the first time." The data will no longer be encrypted after the user unlocks the device and will stay that way even if the user lacks the device again.

Comment: That is why the answer does not use the default

Comment: I wish I could give extra upvotes for actually quoting/linking directly to the documentation

Comment: Since iOS 8.3, all application data are encrypted unless being shared intentionally, and all accesses are prohibited. That is why raw file browsers and jailbreaking all became history. While I'm not happy about this in certain situations but it's the right thing to do. :)

Comment: @jack Jailbreaks and file browsers still exist and can work. Using data protection explicitly is still a recommended best practice and was discussed at length at WWDC this year.

Comment: @jack 'Since iOS 8.3, all application data are encrypted unless being shared intentionally', would it be possible to point to the documentation on this?  IE is the data encrypted all the time (even when the phone is unlocked)?

Comment: @lostintranslation: sorry, I don't know the documentation, but all the iOS "file browser" apps (that I know of) stop working and there is no new jail-break "release" either. There are still some claimed jail-break tricks but they are not the real ones anymore.