# How to test if Core Data SQLlite file is encrypted?

Tags: ios, core-data, encryption, nsfilemanager

Core Data seems to be encrypted by default when device is locked but only before the first unlock.

From [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW54)

> For apps built for iOS 5.0 or later, persistent stores now store data
>   by default in an encrypted format on disk. The default protection
>   level prevents access to the data until after the user unlocks the
>   device for the first time.

So I set it up to get encrypted whenever the device is locked. The encryption settings for the SQLite file are set before  returning the _persistentStoreCoordinator like so:

```
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:fileAttributes ofItemAtPath:storeURL.path error:&error]) {
        //Handle error
    }
return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Code is from [here](https://nickharris.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/core-data-and-enterprise-iphone-applications-protecting-your-data/).

I would like to test if the file is really encrypted.

What I did is lock the device and download the app container using Xcode->Window->Devices. However the file is not shown in the container. If I do the same when the device is unlocked I can then find it in the container. Why is that? More importantly can I test to see that the file gets encrypted when the phone is locked or it being missing is proof enough.

---

**EDIT**: A better setting up encryption for Core Data per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23203728) suggestion would be:

```
NSDictionary *storeOptions = @{NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey: NSFileProtectionComplete};
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:storeOptions error:&error]){
    //handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I did is lock the device and download the app container using
>   Xcode->Window->Devices. However the file is not shown in the
>   container. If I do the same when the device is unlocked I can then
>   find it in the container.

From what I understand this is how Apple encryption works. When your device is locked you don't see encrypted files in the device container, when it is open you do see them.