# iOS Data protection on core data not working

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to enable the data protection for my core data file. Here is what I did.

1. Project settings enabled the data protection in capabilities.
2. Modified persistent store coordinator getter

   ```
   let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
   let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")

   var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
   do {
       try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: [NSSQLitePragmasOption : ["journal_mode" : "DELETE"], NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey : NSFileProtectionComplete])
   }
   ```
3. Ran the code and installed the app on the device.
4. Downloaded the app container and opened package content, and could see the .sqlite file
5. Now locked the device
6. Kept it for 10 sec, and then downloaded the app container again for the same app.
   7.Opened the package content, I can still see the package content and sqlite file :(

I am using free provisioning profile if that helps in anyway.

What mistake am I doing here?? Why is this .sqlite file is not encrypted?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicates : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23203728/3400991 , To encrypt persistent store SQLCipher should be used

Comment: @shobhakar-tiwari : I don't see how is that a duplicate !!! 1. I have an answer exactly same as the one given in your link and yet am claiming that its not encrypting that means the code I wrote is not working!!!! 2. The answer posted in your link has not been accepted so not very sure did it actually work or not!!!. I have found 100 such links having the same code none of them either accepted nor works.

Comment: use SqlCipher , thats why its written as **possible duplicate** not exact duplicate

Comment: @shobhakar-tiwari : You are missing a point here buddy! SqlCipher is an open source extension to sqlite to encrypt the entire sqlite file. I am not asking for the ways to encrypt my core data. Question is very specific!! I want to make use of NSFileProtection to utilise the data protection feature provided by apple from iPhone 3gs onwards which encrypts and decrypts the file by placing it in a formatted disk partition. So using SqlCipher is anyway out of scope here :)

Comment: Then mention this in question also otherwise it seems u want way of securing your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the computer your device is connected to is a Trusted Computer, it can read your app's container even if the device is locked. I know of two options to test if the sqlite file is encrypted:

1) Jailbreak your device. Then SSH into your device, and try to read the sqlite file (ie. 'cat sqlite_file') when the device is locked. If the file is encrypted, you won't be able to read it.

2) You can inspect the attributes on the sqlite file and make sure the `NSFileProtectionKey` attribute is appropriately set:

```
let attributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: sqlite_path)
print(attributes)
```