# ResearchKit : Offline use in iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, offline, researchkit

I have read this tutorial http://researchkit.org/blog.html and https://www.raywenderlich.com/104575/researchkit-tutorial-with-swift.

In my application I do not want to use any server and keep me application for devices only (Planning to store data using coredata).Also confusion is if i store data in coredata then how can I maintain HIPAA standard for medical data ?

But I am not clear on how to design this architecture.Please help me with it.

I want to create data for two roles patient and researcher.

Please help me by guiding on how to start with this.

Comment: I advise using Realm.io to store the data

Comment: What is HIPAA standard? I understand, you determine user role(e.g.patient) when user sign up and store data in local for user's role. But another user has diffirent role(researcher),when researcher sign in, researcher see paient's data because you store data in local. Please tell more detail.

Comment: CoreData has an option to be encrypted on disk.  [See this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23203728/266252)